# Где может хранится текст apk приложения?

Tags: android, xml, apk

Очень нужно найти весь текст, который есть в приложении. Я посмотрел activity_main.xml и все .xml в layout, но не нашёл. Где он ещё может быть ? Могу скинуть apk

Comment: Где угодно может храниться, хоть в коде собираться по буквам.

Answer (score 0):

Строки в Android приложении хранятся в `res/values/strings.xml`